# Benchmarking Float Precision per Operation in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, 32bit-64bit

I want to benchmark the error between 64-bit floats and 32 bit floats in Numpy for addition and multiplication. Unfortunately, I could not find exactly what I was looking for when searching for the associated keywords.

My intuition is that with each arithmetic operation the error will propagate and accumulate.

Thus the idea is to plot the error per operation over the number of operations. I would expect the error to converge to some non-zero constant for large numbers of operations. Instead, the multiplication error converges to zero and the summation error seems random.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

size = 9999

test_64 = np.random.rand((size))
test_32 = test_64.astype(np.float32).astype(np.float64)

out     = np.empty((size,2))

for i in range(size):

    # summation error
    sum_64  = np.sum(test_64[:i])
    sum_32  = np.sum(test_32[:i])
    sum_er  = np.abs((sum_32) - sum_64) / (i+1)
    sum_er  = np.log(sum_er)

    # multiplication error
    mul_64  = np.prod(test_64[:i])
    mul_32  = np.prod(test_32[:i])
    mul_er  = np.abs((mul_32) - mul_64) / (i+1)
    mul_er  = np.log(mul_er)

    out[i,0] = sum_er
    out[i,1] = mul_er

x = np.linspace(1,size,size)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(x,out[:,0])
axs[1].plot(x,out[:,1])
```

Am I on the wrong track or is this actually how the errors behave? Why would the error per multiplication decrease with each multiplication?

Would this behave differently if I did not use the built-in Numpy functions and iterate over the arrays instead?

Comment: Your multiplication error goes to zero because your *products* go to zero too.

Comment: Interesting experiment. Using relative error rather than absolute error would be more informative. You are multiplying random numbers between 0,1 so the product is tending to zero hence the absolute error is tending to zero as well.  If you haven't done so already, you might enjoy reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithemtic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Because the more random floats I include, the more floats close close to zero are included? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `test_64.astype(np.float32).astype(np.float64)` strikes me as a bit weird: if you are comparing 32-bit arithmetic vs. 64 bit arithmetic, why cast back to 64 bits? Also -- rather than taking logs prior to plotting, you could just use `axs[0].semilogy(x,out[:,0])` (which will handle log(0) more gracefully).

Comment: I've found that in Numpy, if you do arithmetic with 32 bit and 64 bit objects, the 64 bit ones will be cast to 32 bit and the difference between the two objects will be zero. So the Idea was to create a bottleneck by casting back and forth. Although I don't know what exactly happens when 32 bits are cast to 64.